# PHP Backend Framework for Mobile Web (jQuery) Android and iOS Applications

Tags: php, json, jquery-mobile

So I have a simple jQuery Mobile site interfacing with a MySQL database via PHP. Users orders are queried initially, then updated using the mobile web interface. I am not using any PHP framework, just 7 or 8 PHP files I've written for retrieving, updating, creating, and deleting order records.

As I begin to develop the Android and iOS applications, I realized it would be beneficial to have a PHP backend framework that can handle requests to create/read/update/delete my orders and users records from any of the 3 sources without caring which one it is. I want to create a layer of abstraction between the server side database handling and each of the 3 mobile interfaces. I envision being able to make a POST call from the client side, passing a TYPE argument and a JSON array of the data to a generic page like /myserver/mRequest.php, which would determine what to do based on TYPE and handle the processing, returning a STATUS variable and a JSON array of data back to the client.

Is there a good (preferably free) PHP framework that will help layout the backend? I've looked at Zend and a few others, but they seem pretty heavy and intended for desktop sites. I want to minimize the number of calls to the server as well as the amount of data thats sent back and forth (we all know how slow Verizon 3G is).

I'm hoping theres some lightweight framework out there that can be a skeleton for me to organize CRUD functions, check for null values, handle MySQL errors, etc...

If not, a guide to developing a PHP mobile backend would be the next best thing.

Note: I apologize it there is a thread already asking this, but I couldn't find one that I thought fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost any of the major free frameworks would do the trick, Symfony for example handles regular page templating for your jQM pages and handles ajax nicely too.

However, if you only require the framework for the AJAX handling and something broader, you might be advised to develop your simple scripts, with less effort and less of a learning curve (of course, the learning may be part and parcel of your plan).

Another option is a Data Abstraction layer between your scripts and your PHP, this would give you greater flexibility in terms of your data changes, but not burden you with a hefty framework in between. Propel and Doctrine are worth a look and are often used as part of web frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I personally really like [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com), which is a very clean and powerfull lightweight PHP framework with easy database-access.

Just have a look at it.

Greetings, 
Steffen

Comment: So using CodeIgnitor or CakePHP, for example, I would create a main controller for my application, then a controller to handle each database type? Ie, a controller for CRUD operations on Orders, one for Users, one for Products, etc.... Am I understanding this correctly?